# Generate RTF, PDF and MS XML output files

Tags: objective-c, pdf, openxml, rtf, docx

Does anyone have any suggestions for generating RTF, PDF and MS XML reports from XCODE ?

I was thinking of creating some Objective-C classes to help do this but no doubt some may already exist.

Comment: XCode is a development environment. Do you want to generate some docs from your coding environmeet (with a plugin), or from a program you've written that runs on Mac ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question...

Subclass NSDocument and generate formatted text using NSAttributedString, NSTextBlock, NSParagraphsStyle and so on...

Add the attributedString to the NSDocuments textStorage.

Add some methods to NSDocument to provide the list of supported output formats available from NSAttributedString to the Save As dialog.

It's not simple but works OK and can be used to generate formatted documents.

Things I can't figure out how to do are the following:

- Make use of RTF \stylesheets so that MS Word picks up the styles used
  by the different programs.
- Creating new Sections, Chapters and Pages (e.g. RTF tag \page)
- Creating Headers and Footers.

If anyone knows whether any of these are supported by the Apple text system please let me know.  I can do this with custom RTF generator but would prefer to stick to standard API's if they exist.
Thanks